# How to change color of background by current value of select?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Using asp-core net 2.2 mvc, I would like to change the background color of div tag by the current value of select

I have defined the following select in a view:

```
<div id="bgcolor" class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="BackGround" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="BackGround" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BackGroundColor>()" onchange="changeBackground">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then I added the script:

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script>
    function changeBackground(value) {
        $("#bgcolor").removeClass("bg-primary bg-secondary bg-warning").addClass(value)
    };
</script>
}
```

The  enum has the following values

```
public enum BackGroundColor
{
    bg-primary,
    bg-secondary,
    bg-success,
    bg-danger,
    bg-warning,
}
```

I am not even sure if the script is loaded.
Could you please indicate the correct way?

Comment: remove the `#` from `id="#bgcolor"`

Comment: I did remove the # but still nothing happens when i change the selection

Comment: Where is `value` coming from?

Comment: Check whether the class name is adding or not on change, using inspectelement, if it not adding please provide working example using stackbliz or fiddle

Comment: @Ryan  it should be selected value of select. I tried also with
 onchange="changeBackground('bg-warning')" but nothing

Comment: @Sethuraman I will let you know

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing value as an arguement to the onchange function? `onchange="changeBackground(value)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select asp-for="BackGround" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BackGroundColor>()" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
```

```js
function changeBackground(data)
{
//put this data.value where ever you want
alert(data.value);
}
```

```js
 $("#bgcolor").removeClass("bg-primary bg-secondary bg-warning").addClass(data.value);
```

please try.

Comment: Thanks to you I found correct way
 
function changeBackground(e) {
            $("#bgcolor").removeClass("bg-primary bg-secondary bg-warning").addClass(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
        };

Comment: did the above answer helped you or you find it by yourself?@Ozzy

Comment: data.value returns the current value of enum as integer. You have to get the text of selected as 
data.options[data.selectedIndex].text